# Random sample draw for each column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a data.frame in R, but I don't have a strong background in R or in writing code.  What I am trying to do is create a data.frame where each column has a range of integers without repeating.  In other words, I want each column to have, for example, the number 1 through 15 in a random order.  How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll generally get better help if you include what you have tried so far and why it isn't working.  Also, make sure to look here and on google for answers to your questions before posting.. as this has been asked before.  However, to point you in a direction: take a look at the `sample` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example the answer to this question is actually really instructive to your question.

Comment: This is called a **permutation**, which might help your google search: http://people.reed.edu/~jones/141/Permutations.html

Answer (score 1):

```
data.frame(a=sample(1:15,15),b=sample(1:15,15))

    a  b
1  12 11
2  10 12
3   3  9
4   9  3
5   7  6
6   4  8
7   1 10
8  14  7
9  15  2
10  2  4
11  6 14
12 11  5
13  8 13
14 13 15
15  5  1
```

Comment: or even more compactly `as.data.frame(replicate(2,sample(1:15)))`